# Avoid self-closing element in BeanIO

Tags: xml, formatting

In BeanIO, how to avoid serialize an empty element as a self-closing element.

Current setting:  < TYPE/ > 
Expected result:  < TYPE >< /TYPE >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find proper approach to handle the case in BeanIO. So, it handled manually by adding a method and checking whether the XML is empty, consequently value of endTag "< /${elementName}>" is applied to avoid self-closing.